# Dynamic HTML element creation

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, dynamic

I have created HTML canvas element dynamically while changing the number of element size to more, it uses the previously created element instead of creating all new object, hence the binding also not cleared.

here is my code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of rows; let i=index">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let j of cols; let j=index">
      <div id="Div{{(i * cols.length) + j}}">
        <canvas id="Canv{{(i * cols.length) + j}}" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste the code here ?

Comment: u think we can fix ur code without seeing it?

Comment: Your question needs more clarity as well as some or all of the code you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't creating a new element each time, you will find that all modifications are being made against the same reference, like this:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');

function addElement(w: number, h: number) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua';
    div.style.width = w + 'px';
    div.style.height = h + 'px';

    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

addElement(100, 100);

addElement(20, 20);
```

Here is a working version, creating a new element each time...

```
function addElement(w: number, h: number) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua';
    div.style.width = w + 'px';
    div.style.height = h + 'px';

    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

addElement(100, 100);

addElement(20, 20);
```